# Geometry node "Collection Info" Reset children and Separate Children Breaks Geometry

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to use the collection info node, but when I check "Reset Children" or "Separate Children," it doesn't change anything, and if I check both it completely breaks the geometry.

[image: Node with nothing checked]

[image: Node with Separation checked]

[image: Node with both checked (geometry demolished)]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! There are a hundred thousand questions here about the donut tutorial, and they are almost always the same problems: You would have to additionally activate *Pick Instance* and apply the transformation of the sprinkles. Please use the [search](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeometry-nodes%5D+donut).